# how can I specify file directory for csv file in c++?

Tags: c++, file, csv, directory, ifstream

I'm not very good at c++ but I need to perform operations on data in csv file.

the file is in the format of days versus classification such that for example,

```
    revenues,profit,volume
    481.21,144.36,30
    449.13,134.74,28
    544.11,163.23,34
    368.93,110.68,23
```

so that first row specifies classification, and from 2nd row and forward, enlists day1, day2, day3 .... etc

.cpp .csv and the executable program are in the same directory, but I suspected that it's not reading my file correctly.

so I did a simple test and coded the following lines just to see if it can print the data as days versus classifications but it gives me 0's everywhere

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);
ifstream fin("data.csv");
int days = 1;
double revenues,profit,volume;
while (fin >> revenues >> profit >> volume){
    O[1][days] = revenues;
    O[2][days] = profit;
    O[3][days] = volume;
    days++;
}
for (int t = 1; t <= days; t++){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        cout << O[i][t] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And remember that array indexes are *zero* based (i.e. an array of three elements have indexes `0`, `1` and `2`).

Comment: are you sure that your binary is also in the same folder as your csv file? And please specify your error. Does it open the file or what exactly doesn't workt?

Comment: It doesn't matter where your `cpp` file is or where your *binary* program is, what matters is where you ran your program from.

Comment: Also it is the *current working directory* when you *run* the program that is important when it comes to finding files in the "current" directory. If you're using an IDE then the location of the source files, the location of executable program, and the working directory might all be different.

Comment: You should check for errors after opening the file. `if(!fin.is_open()) std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';`

Comment: To be honest, I've never heard of "current working directory" and how I can modify it. I'm using dev-c++ and whenever I run, the executable program is stored in the same directory as that of .csv file, that of the .cpp file. I still get, instead of values for each days versus headings, 0's for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not important where the .cpp file is located. It is important where the .exe file is located(compiled code which will be executed). If both the .exe and the .csv file are in the same directory then it's all good.

Your problem is the way you are reading; if you make a quick debug you will see that the while block is never executed because `(fin >> revenues >> profit >> volume)` will fail from the first time. The reason is the way the extraction operator `>>` for streams work. More details you can find everywhere (like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)). The short story: it fails to read a double from the stream because values are separated by commas. It will read a string until a space shows (including the comma) and it will try to parse that string to a double and it will fail.

You should try something like reading line by line. You split the line into three values and use those.

Or you can read strings until commas and parse those strings to double values. I've put up some code:

```
string line;

while (fin.good()){
    std::getline (fin, line);
    stringstream line_stream(line);
    string value;

    std::getline (line_stream, value, ',');
    O[1][days] = atof(value.c_str());
    std::getline (line_stream, value, ',');
    O[2][days] = atof(value.c_str());
    std::getline (line_stream, value, ',');
    O[3][days] = atof(value.c_str());
    days++;
}
```

The `std::getline()` reads a string until newline or ','.

Or you can simply search for some dedicated CSV library in C++ and use it directly.

Comment: That helped in a sense that I do get numbers found in the data but the printed out version do not match the actual data i.e. say, for 1 = revenues, 2 = profit, 3 = volume, then printed O[2][25] != the profit on 25th day and is actually, say, revenues on 31st day kinda thing.

Comment: @KevvyKim, this can have multiple causes, e.g the way you put the data in your array named "O" or the format of your file. Please add the new version of your code with some data as input.

Comment: I just updated how the data is formatted. Apply the similar notion of getline but should I include for loops for i and days for O[i][days] ?

Comment: Yes. It may be related to the way you put the data in your array. For example, on the version of the code you have posted, "days" starts with the value 50 when you do the reading. Then, when you print the data you start from day 1. Hence, the elements from 0 to 50 in "O" are not initialized but printed out. Not sure what your logic is, but it does not sound ok.

Comment: oh damn, that was a typo. Originally, days starts with 1, thus int days = 1;

Comment: aaaahhhh the problem was so stupid. I needed to add commas at the end of every line. i.e. add a comma after volume, and after every number of volumes. Then I added for loops for get line and it's working well. Thank you though

Comment: By the way, if I save a similar excel file as csv, then is there a way to add commas at the end of every line?

Comment: Ah, it was my bad. You don't need to add commas at the end of the line. I have updated the code. It was std::getline() causing troubles, it continues to read until it finds a comma or end of stream. So I have added line_stream as an intermediate element. It should work now.